# How to register multiple beans using single @Bean-annotated method (or similar) in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I have a class similar to the following:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private <T> T createService(Class<T> serviceInterface) {
        // implementation omitted
    }

    @Bean
    public FooService fooService() {
        return createService(FooService.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public BarService barService() {
        return createService(BarService.class);
    }

    ...

}
```

The problem is that there are too many @Bean-annotated methods which differ only in their names, return types and arguments for the `crateService` method call.
I would like to make this class similar to the following:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private static final Class<?>[] SERVICE_INTERFACES = {
            FooSerivce.class, BarService.class, ...};


    private <T> T createService(Class<T> serviceInterface) {
        // implementation omitted
    }

    @Beans // whatever
    public Map<String, Object> serviceBeans() {
        Map<String, Object> result = ...
        for (Class<?> serviceInterface : SERVICE_INTERFACES) {
            result.put(/* calculated bean name */,
                    createService(serviceInterface));
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Is it possible in Spring?

Comment: Of course yes. But you will have only one injectable bean in the application context : the map.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what you're trying to achieve? I don't see how having many @ Bean annotated methods with different return types and names is a problem. Ideally you will group those @ Bean methods in separate @ Configuration classes, so you won't have one God class holding the whole configuration. You can @ Import different configuration classes to reuse defined @ Bean methods.

Comment: I also have exact same requirement. In my case, I am first reading the config data from a file and for each entry in the config, I need to create a bean (all of same java type with different data). Hence I cannot use @Bean annotation, as it has to be read from a config

Comment: @hovanessyan Harish explained the problem. I don't know how much beans will be registered, so I can't hardcode them as separate `@Bean`-annotated methods.

Comment: @Victor if the problem is what Harish described, you can try a different approach. If all the "beans" are the same java type, you can do use a single @ Bean which has a field - collection of the java type of each entry from the file, or you may consider not using Spring Beans at all.

Answer (score 7):

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerServices() {
        beanFactory.registerSingleton("service...", new NNNService());
        ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.

Comment: `@PostConstruct` needs a no-arg method. This isn't helpful if you need to inject beans & properties

Comment: `@PostConstruct` runs after the beans and properties have been injected into the `@Configuration` object. (and in his example he's even using an injected bean factory)

Comment: This has a nasty pattern where the registered beans aren't necessarily available when expected.