# Spring java config: register multiple spring beans by one java method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-config

I'm trying to migrate project to Spring Boot. Previously Guice was used as DI.

We have such guice module

```
public class RepositoryImplementationModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        new Reflections("com.example").getTypesAnnotatedWith(Repository.class)
            .forEach(repositoryClass -> 
                bind((Class) repositoryClass).toProvider(new RepositoryProvider(repositoryClass)));
    }
}
```

This is pretty simple to understand if you familiar with spring data.
Implementation of interfaces is generated on app startup based on method names by some library.

Based on this question [How to register multiple beans using single @Bean-annotated method (or similar) in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260500/how-to-register-multiple-beans-using-single-bean-annotated-method-or-similar)

I've create this configuration

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryImplementationConfig {
    @Inject
    public RepositoryImplementationConfig(ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory) {
        new Reflections("com.example").getTypesAnnotatedWith(Repository.class)
            .forEach(repository -> {
                configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(makeBeanName(repository), generateImplementation(repository));
            });
    }

    private <T extends Class> String makeBeanName(T clazz) {
        //just convert class name to spring bean name
        return "";
    }

    private <T extends Class> T generateImplementation(T clazz) {
        //make a proxy of class and generate implementation by method names
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

I have services which use repositories. In example:

```
@Component
public class MyService {
    @Inject
    public MyService(AnswerRepository answerRepository) {
        System.out.println(answerRepository.findAnswer());
    }
}
```

When I tried to run this I've got an error:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.MyService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.AnswerRepository' that could not be found.

I add `@DependsOn("repositoryImplementationConfig")` to MyService - it works, but I have a lot of services, so it's not convenient way to fix this.

I've tried to play with `@Order`, `@Prority`, `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` but nothing.

At the end I've come up with this ugly hack. It works, but it definitely not the right way to do things

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Inject
    RepositoryImplementationConfig repositoryImplementationConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

Questions:

1. What is the spring way of doing thing like it was in Guice? Am I on the right way?
2. Is there any better solution to initialize `RepositoryImplementationConfig` before `MyService`?

Comment: If those are `spring-data` repositories and you are using Spring Boot you have to do nothing and they will be detected automatically. So basically you are making things more complex, just ditch your configuration.

Comment: That's not spring data repository.

Comment: You should't use a `@Configuration` class then. Use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to register additional beans.

Comment: Wow, `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is exactly what I need. So, my result is `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to create definition of `FactoryBean`, which is a spring equivalent to Provider. The same logic as it was in guice.

Comment: how have you defined AnswerRepository bean ? Define if its not and make sure  it is loaded by spring container.

Comment: Actually, that was my question: how to define repository beans? First I've tried `ConfigurableBeanFactory` (code above) and then  `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which did the trick.